# Unicorn always serializes items which have fallback enabled

Tags: unicorn

We recently started using Unicorn for synchronization in our project to sync content and templates.

We are using Sitecore 8.2 (rev. 161221) and Unicorn 4.0.3

The issue we are facing is that every time we run a sync, all content items, for which there is language fallback implemented on template level, get synced irrespective of any changes made to them. 
As there are lot of content items being synced, it takes a very long for the sync to complete.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in Unicorn 4.0.4 and onward.

Full list of fixes in 4.0.4 here: https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn/milestone/4?closed=1

Unicorn and Rainbow relies on running in a site context where dataprovider level features such as Language Fallback and EnforceVersionPresence are disabled - so it can read "what's really stored" without any artificial API injection.

Answer (score 1):

I started getting the same problem after an upgrade.

More specifically each and every time I ran unicorn sync I would get every item being updated:

```
> Field __Updated by - en#1 - Reset to standard value
```

A similar issue is also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40617232/unicorn-syncing-same-sitecore-items-again-and-again)

I found that the following combination helped clear this up.

1. Running the Sync (you will see the above messages)
2. Reserializing
3. Sync again (messages are gone)